# Monkey-patching ruby method with bang

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching

Is it possible to monkey-patch a method with a bang at the end?

I want to monkey-patch `String.upcase!`, but I don't know how to achieve that.

The problem is that I want to change the original string object.

Here's an example:

```
class String
  def upcase!
    self.mb_chars.upcase.to_s
  end
end
```

Now if I type that in console and try it out, it doesn't work:

```
[1] pry(main)> asd="asd"
=> "asd"
[2] pry(main)> asd.upcase
=> "ASD"
[3] pry(main)> asd
=> "asd"
[4] pry(main)> asd.upcase!
=> "ASD"
[5] pry(main)> asd
=> "asd"
```

Comment: It's no different to a method without a bang at the end

Comment: Caveat: it is *your* responsibility to have the method modify the caller, if that's what you intend. But that's no different to it being your responsibility to *not* modify the caller when you monkey patch the same method without a bang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is independent of the method having a bang. If you want to replace the receiver string, use the method `String#replace`.

```
class String
  def foo
    replace(whatever_string_you_want_to_replace_the_receiver_with)
  end
end
```

You can perhaps put `mb_chars.upcase` as the argument to `replace`.

Answer (score 6):

You should avoid monkey patching top-level class like `String`. If you want to know why, I strongly recommend you to read [Monkeypatching is Destroying Ruby by Avdi Grimm](http://devblog.avdi.org/2008/02/23/why-monkeypatching-is-destroying-ruby/).

Now to answer your question, you could do something like this:

```
class String
  def upcase!
    replace(upcase) # self is not mandatory here
  end
end

> s = "foo"
 => "foo"
> s.upcase
 => "FOO"
> s
 => "foo"
> s.upcase!
 => "FOO"
> s
 => "FOO"
```

Answer (score 1):

The bang is just part of the method name. It has absolutely no special meaning whatsoever. You write a method with a bang at the end the exact same way you write a method with an 'o' or a 'z' at the end.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
class String
  def upcase!
     #Your logic here
  end
end
```

Comment: I need to replace original string. I know I can write what you wrote, but can you show me some example that will replace original string?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really understand what the problem you're trying to handle. Please update the question with more details.